# Как задать переменной тип, описанный в wsdl-ле?

Tags: 1с, php

Всем привет. Очередной вопрос.

Можно ли задать **php** переменной тип, описанный в **wsdl**-ле.

```
Определение = Новый WSОпределения("http://link?wsdl", "user");
Прокси = Новый WSПрокси(Определение, "http://localhost/ws/PacketGetProductTable", "WSGetProductTable", "WSGetProductTableSoap");              
Прокси.Пользователь = "user";         
ТабТип = Прокси.ФабрикаXDTO.Тип("http://localhost/ws/PacketGetProductTable", "Request");
Таб = Прокси.ФабрикаXDTO.Создать(ТабТип);

Таб.ProductCode = "";
СтрокаТип = Прокси.ФабрикаXDTO.Тип("http://localhost/ws/PacketGetProductTable", "ParametrTableRow");
СтрокаRequest = Прокси.ФабрикаXDTO.Создать(СтрокаТип);
СтрокаRequest.Name  = "";
СтрокаRequest.Value  = "";
Таб.ParametrTable.Добавить(СтрокаRequest);
Данные =  Прокси.GetProductTable(Таб);
```

А лучше не подскажете аналог такой функции на ПХП, ну или куда смотреть и где почитать?

Особенно интересуют функции: **WSПрокси**,**ФабрикаXDTO.Тип** и **ФабрикаXDTO.Создать**.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[Справочная информация по SOAP в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.soap.php)

[Практическое использование SOAP в PHP 5](http://php.su/articles/?cat=pear&page=004)